# Error during couchdb filtered replication with params

Tags: couchdb, replication

I'm trying to run a filtered replication on two different machines, I realized that this only happens when doing a pull replication, if I do a push replication it works fine.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d '{\"source\":\"http://MARTIN-NEWPC:5984/pdlib\",\"target\":\"pdlib\",\"filter\":\"replication/SINGLE_COLLECTION\",\"query_params\":{\"key\":\"bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872\"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The cryptic response I get from that request is:

```
{"error":"json_encode", "reason":"{bad_term, <0.20050.0>}"}
```

And the debug output in the target couchdb log file is:

```
[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [debug] [<0.476.0>] 'GET' /pdlib/_changes?key=bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872&filter=replication/SINGLE_COLLECTION&style=all_docs&heartbeat=10000&since=0&feed=normal {1,
                                                                                                                                                        1}
Headers: [{'Accept',"application/json"},
          {'Content-Length',"0"},
          {'Host',"MARTIN-NEWPC:5984"},
          {'User-Agent',"CouchDB/1.0.2"}]

[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [debug] [<0.476.0>] OAuth Params: [{"key","bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872"},
               {"filter","replication/SINGLE_COLLECTION"},
               {"style","all_docs"},
               {"heartbeat","10000"},
               {"since","0"},
               {"feed","normal"}]

[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [info] [<0.476.0>] 192.168.2.3 - - 'GET' /pdlib/_changes?key=bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872&filter=replication/SINGLE_COLLECTION&style=all_docs&heartbeat=10000&since=0&feed=normal 200

[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [error] [<0.476.0>] attempted upload of invalid JSON (set log_level to debug to log it)

[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [debug] [<0.476.0>] Invalid JSON: <<"bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872">>

[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [info] [<0.476.0>] 192.168.2.3 - - 'GET' /pdlib/_changes?key=bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872&filter=replication/SINGLE_COLLECTION&style=all_docs&heartbeat=10000&since=0&feed=normal 400

[Mon, 17 Oct 2011 01:20:48 GMT] [debug] [<0.476.0>] httpd 400 error response:
 {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

In case you need to know, this is the filter function:

```
function (doc, req) {
    if (doc.type == 'collection' || doc.type == 'document') {
        for (var i in doc.path) {
            if (doc.path[i] == req.query.key) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas about the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

It's common to get a 400 "invalid UTF-8 JSON" error when CouchDB tries to interpret one of your query values as JSON when it's a raw (unquoted) string instead. In this case the replication config results in this HTTP request:

```
GET /pdlib/_changes?key=bb579347-9bfb-4dda-84eb-622b43108872&filter=replication/SINGLE_COLLECTION&style=all_docs&heartbeat=10000&since=0&feed=normal 400
```

The _changes feed itself doesn't use a `key` parameter, but normal CouchDB _view queries do — and there expect it to be a JSON value! — so you might try renaming that query_param to something different.

(Somewhat unfortunately, user-defined filter (and list, etc.) functions share the query parameter namespace with CouchDB itself...you may want to prefix your custom parameters with something that's unlikely to conflict with current or future builtin options, e.g. `myapp_key`.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look, I'm passing the quoted value, otherwise as you said, I get a JSON error (this only works with push replication). Also, query_param is the only "documented" parameter name I found to pass parameters into a replication filter and inside the function you have to use 'req.query' to get them, how would I get my param in the filter function using the myapp_key param?. I had to workaround this issue by just using push replication in my solution, I was on a big hurry trying to finish it, I'll try to keep digging around when I get some free time.

Comment: What I mean is, store a replication doc with `query_params:{prefixed_key:somevalue}` instead of `query_params:{key:somevalue}`. Then look for `req.query.prefixed_key` instead of `req.query.key`. This is just a hunch, but I suspect CouchDB is treating query.key special.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there is something wrong with the way you have your JSON escaped. This works for me:

curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d '{"source":"source_db","target":"target_db","filter":"ddoc/filter-name","query_params":{"key":"some_key"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"